# Where do the files and folders created by a Chrome App reside in file system?

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems, google-chrome-app

First I have to say I'm very new to Google Chrome App development. I'm using `webkitRequestFileSystem` to create folders and files dynamically from my app.

Now where can I find the folders and files in my file system, or is there any other way to see them?

Answer (score 1):

It will be buried deep into your Chrome profile, **with all file names and paths obfuscated and complex metadata dependencies**.

Something along the lines (from the root of the profile folder):

```
Storage/ext/your_app_id_here/def/File System/
```

The filesystem is virtual: it's not expected to map to a location within a user's filesystem, and **you're not expected to be able to access it outside Chrome**. The fact it's actually stored as a collection of files that correspond to virtual files is but a technical implementation detail.

If you want to interact with the real filesystem, you need to request access to a folder from the user using [`chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) for Chrome Apps instead of `webkitRequestFileSystem`.

Comment: Is there any way to prepare a localhost server inside chrome app and check the files written via app by hitting the url in browser.

Comment: _Technically_ yes. With access to `chrome.sockets` API, you can, but you'll need to fully implement an HTTP server in JavaScript. Practically, this is a bad idea.